# Error: Exited with code 3 at ChildProcess. when using create-near-app

Tags: ubuntu, nearprotocol

I used create-near-app to struct my project. But when I run `yarn start` it gives me the following error

```
Unexpected error while opening in browser: true
 Error: Exited with code 3
 at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/rasha/voting- app/voying/node_modules/opn/index.js:85:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:441:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:675:12)
```

Local server I opened it from the terminal manually. But I think it can't find the default server anyone can help?

Comment: I would recommended against using create-near-app at this time since it makes a lot of choices for you that are just as easy to make on your own -- except you make them yourself

Comment: Ok I think I do my own also

Answer (score 1):

The **opn** package is responsible for opening the browser.

To disable this feature, set '*open*' in array '*options*' to **false**

In my case:

```
//Gruntfile.js
options: {
    port: 9200,
    open: false, // Change this
    livereload: 35729,
    hostname: 'localhost'
},
```